# Latex, Kile IDE, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: latex, kile

I have been using Latex for a while on Windows but I just converted my Windows machine to Ubuntu only now.  Unfortunately, I have never used Kile before.  I have downloaded texlive 2012 and Kile.  How do I open the Kile IDE with ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Unity? My guess is you are (as that's the default one) and it is simple to access your programs. Click on the Ubuntu Button (Home Button or BFB, "Big Freakin' Button") and then type in Kile in the search box. It should show up and you can start it. 
Note: 
This will only work if you have installed Kile (logically). If you haven't, you can download/install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.